# IPv6 over PPPoe?

Tags: ipv6, pppoe, network-manager

What is the best way to be able to get IPv6 addresses over PPPoe?

I currently use NM-Applet to get internet service from my ISP, but it has no IPv6 tab on PPPOE connections. I wouldn't mind using some command line tool, but it would be nice to transfer my settings from NM-applet to whatever tool if I have to do that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try adding

```
+ipv6 ipv6cp-use-ipaddr
```

to /etc/ppp/options. Depending on how your ISP provides IPv6 this might be enough to give the machine itself IPv6.

Many ISPs assume that a router connects with PPPoE instead of a PC, so this might not work for you. The only way to get IPv6 in this situation is to configure your machine as a router. It should then use DHCP for IPv6 to ask for Prefix Delegation. The prefix it gets can then be used to assign /64 subnets to your networks or your local machine. And if you want to provide IPv6 service to your local networks you should run radvd (router advertisement daemon) to advertise that your machine is a router.

The easiest is to use wide-dhcpdv6 for this. The basic idea is to request prefix delegation from one interface and then use that prefix to assign subnets to other interfaces, like:

```
interface ppp0 {
    # Request Prefix Delegation on ppp0, and give the received prefix id 0
    send ia-pd 0;
};

# Use subnets from the prefix with id 0
id-assoc pd 0 {
    prefix-interface eth0 {
        # Assign subnet 1 to eth0
        sla-id 1;
    };
};
```

Let's say that you received prefix 2001:db8:1234::/48 from your ISP. This example would then assign 2001:db8:1234:1::/64 to eth0.

A basic radvd.conf would look like:

```
interface eth0
{
    AdvSendAdvert on;
    prefix ::/64
    {
        AdvOnLink on;
        AdvAutonomous on;
    };
};
```

Oh, and don't forget to put

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
```

in your /etc/sysctl.conf.

Comment: Oh, and http://www.6deploy.org/workshops/brazil_20080526/autoconf_and_dhcpv6.pdf might also contain useful information!

Comment: Well, I knew about radvd and DHCPv6, but I sure didn't know you could use them over a pppoe interface. Can you use dibbler to request a prefix and then give out addresses on other interfaces? I don't have anything against wide-dhcpv6, but I do already have dibbler set up for one of my home networks. Thanks!

Comment: Should be no problem. IPv6 with PPP (and therefore PPPoE and PPPoA) just create a link. Everything else just works like your local network :-)

Comment: Instead of adding the option to `/etc/ppp/options` I added it to the relevant file in `/etc/ppp/peers` which appears to achieve the same result. I think your answer could be improved slightly by mentioning what `ipv6cp-use-ipaddr` does.

Comment: When I enable IPv6 in the PPP configuration I get a functional default route looking like this: `default via fe80::203:97ff:fe27:c000 dev ppp0  proto ra  metric 1024  expires 65503sec hoplimit 64` but when I enable packet forwarding with `net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding = 1` the default route is removed. I can make the connection work by manually creating the route from the command line, but I am pretty sure that is not how I am supposed to do. Any obvious explanation what I did wrong, or do I need to ask a separate question about that?

Comment: Your system learned its default route from the Router Advertisements (RAs) sent to you from the other side of the PPP connection. When you enable forwarding on Linux the kernel stops processing RAs. If you want to enable receiving RAs even when forwarding you need to set `accept_ra=2` which forces it to `on` even when forwarding is enabled. Also see https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt.

Comment: @SanderSteffann That does work. But it looks like with that approach I will have to change it for the `default` interface because `sysctl.conf` would be loaded before the `ppp0` interface exists. Is there a way to only accept a default route from `ppp0` and not from other interfaces?

Comment: @SanderSteffann I ended up creating a `/etc/ppp/ipv6-up.d/default-route` script with these two lines `#!/bin/sh -e` `ip route add ::/0 via "$LLREMOTE" dev "$PPP_IFACE"`. I'm not sure if I should be using `PPP_REMOTE` or `LLREMOTE` there, both seems to have the same value.

Comment: On a point to point link both should be fine

Answer (score 0):

Sander Steffann's answer is great, but if you found you got the IPv6 address (can be checked via `ip addr` or `ifconfig`), and `mtr -6 www.google.com` was still not working, it might be caused by some sort of default routing assignment in your local router (can be checked via `ip -6 route` or `netstat -6rn`).

One way to solve this issue is to disable RA on your ethernet port, like this (change the existing file in `/etc/netplan/`):

```
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
        enp3s0:
            accept-ra: false
```